# Parse dashboard not loading - color balls spinning around in the center

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I have deployed the parse server on heroku using the parse-server-example. I want to deploy the parse-dashboard also in the same server.

I tried to install the dashboard locally by using the following command.

```
npm install -g parse-dashboard

parse-dashboard --appId yourAppId --masterKey yourMasterKey --serverURL "https://appName.herokuapp.com/parse" --appName appName
```

When I run this command it says,
The dashboard is now available at http://0.0.0.0:4040/

The dashboard loads when I enter that local host in my browser.

I tried to deploy the dashboard by creating a new project in heroku by following the steps given in the below link.
http://android-kill-the-what.blogspot.in/2016/05/heroku-deploy-parse-dashboard-step.html
The dashboard loads now also when I enter https://appName.herokuapp.com/ in my browser.

I tried to deploy the dashboard in the same server where I deployed the parse-server.

Cloned the parse-server-example project from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example .

In the package.json, I added 'parse-dashboard' as dependency.

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "parse-dashboard": "1.0.14"
}
```

In the index.js file, I added the dashboard settings.

```
...
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
...
var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
  "apps": [
    {   // serverURL, appId, masterKey are same as ParseServer's settings
      "serverURL": "https://appName.herokuapp.com/parse",
      "appId": "myAppId",
      "masterKey": "myMasterKey",
      "appName": "appName"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
     {
       "user": username,
       "pass": password
     }
   ]
});
...
// make the Parse Dashboard available at /dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);
...
```

After adding these codes, I ran npm install command in terminal.
After that add, commit and pushed to heroku.

The parse-server works but parse-dashboard not loading.

In Safari, when I enter https://appName.herokuapp.com/ it shows

```
I dream of being a website. Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!
```

But when I enter https://appName.herokuapp.com/dashboard it asks me username and password. After I entered those details, three color balls spins around. Nothing happened after that.

Is there anything am missing?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. Were you able to find a solution to this?